# Правильность согласования членов предложения

Tags: орфография, согласование

Как писать правильно:
"Судья Иванов принял решение в порядке *взаимозаменяемости с судьей* Петровым"? или
"Судья Иванов принял решение в порядке *взаимозаменяемости судьи* Петрова"?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно "взаимозаменяемости (кого) с кем - **с судьёй Петровым**", поскольку нельзя *"**взаимо**заменить"* кого-то, можно ***заменить***:

> Решение принял Судья Иванов, **заменявший судью** Петрова в
>   установленном порядке.

Если важно упомянуть *порядок взамозаменяемости*, то лучше отделить взаимозаменяемость от принятия решения, чтобы не возникало представления о "*взаимозаменяемости в принятии решений*" (напр. вместо Иванова решения может принимать сидящий рядом Петров, мол предусмотрен такой порядок).

> Судья Иванов принял решение, *действуя* в порядке взаимозаменяемости с
>   судьей Петровым.